# How to make a case insensitive list search in C#?

Tags: c#, case-insensitive

I've been trying to make a list search method where I could present the items in the list unaffected and after a week going through every search method I could find I realizes that I'm stuck.

The list (posts) stores arrays if that makes any change, this is the search function I got this far that have worked the best but it's case sensitive,

```
    string searchKey; 
    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter key: ");
    searchKey = Console.ReadLine(); 

    foreach (string result in posts.Where(logg => logg.Contains(searchKey))) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", result);
    }
```

Does so I hope that someone know about some great method that I've missed even if I start to think that I'm screwed and should go for some other system instead.

Comment: While playing around I think I found a way to make it work;

         (logg => logg.ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.ToUpper())))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IndexOf` with a case-insensitive comparison:

```
var query = posts.Where(
    logg => logg.IndexOf(searchKey, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);
foreach (string result in query) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", result);
}
```

Note that while I'd expect this to work for `IEnumerable<T>`, I suspect that many `IQueryable<T>` providers (e.g. EF) may well not support this operation.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that one works like a charm, I've been trying the "StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase" earlier but without the "query" part so I've never got it working, thank you for your time. :)

Comment: @PerlyX: The same code inlined would have worked just as well - I only used as separate variable to help readability.

Comment: Okey, then it must have been some other part I missed out on, I'll take notes from this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do a case insensitive search, but where you don't have one available you can simply make all the strings the same case:

```
string lowerSearchKey = searchKey.ToLower();
foreach (string result in posts.Where(logg => logg.ToLower().Contains(lowerSearchKey))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", result);
}
```

Obviously this has performance implications as you are calling `ToLower` repeatedly for each search so you'd probably want to consider storing the all lower case version of the text you are searching:

```
string lowerSearchKey = searchKey.ToLower();
foreach (string result in posts.Where(lowerLogg => lowerLogg.Contains(lowerSearchKey))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", result);
}
```

It's a bit brute force, and may have implications in certain cultures (e.g. Turkish) where the conversion between upper and lower case is not the same as it is in the Latin alphabet, but if you have no other choice it's often what you have to do.

Comment: Found that this could work as well to keep the code down a little, though it's a valid point in saving to lower versions so I'll look in to that too, thank you. :)

          foreach (string result in posts.Where(logg => logg.ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.ToUpper())))

Comment: Note that this has some odd implications around the Turkish culture as well. In general, using a case-insensitive search is better in terms of correctness than lower-casing and then performing a case-sensitive search. Text is hard :(

Comment: @JonSkeet - ah, yes. I'd forgotten that. I'll add a note.